# How is $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{\ast }$ defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, real-numbers

I don't know what set $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{\ast }$ usually denote? How is it defined? Does it contain zero ? Does it contain infinity?

Comment: I saw it on a paper about trans-Sasakian manifolds.

Comment: My guess is the multiplicative group of positive real numbers (so zero would be excluded).  Usually that has either the $*$ or the $+$, not both.

Comment: It would help to see the actual paper.

Comment: The paper might be copyrighted. Here is the paper:http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00009-012-0217-1

Comment: I browsed the paper, this confirms what was said below. Note how a $\sigma$ is defined with image in the set in the set in question and then $1/\sqrt{\sigma}$ is considered, which mainly makes sense when it is positive and non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat common notation for $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon x > 0\}$. 
It does contain neither $0$ nor $+\infty$.

Further, $\mathbb{R}^{\ast} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon x \neq  0\}$ and 
$\mathbb{R}_+ = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon x \geq  0\}$.

---

**Update:** Browsing the paper confirms what was said above. A $\sigma$ is defined with image in the set $\mathbb{R}^{\ast}_+$  and then $1/\sqrt{\sigma}$ is considered, which makes sense essentially only when it is positive and non-zero.

The notation $\mathbb{R}_+$ is also used latter on.

Comment: In short, $\displaystyle R_+^*=(0,+\infty)$

Comment: Yes, but it would be more in tone to use $]0, + \infty[$. :-)

Comment: Ah yes. I used to use that notation when I started with set theory. But now, the first brackets are easier for me to denote openness. Everyone has their preference, right?

Comment: Sure. what I was getting at is that the notation asked about is rather a French, maybe Bourbaki one, as is the interval notation I used.

Comment: Oh! My bad. I didn't know it was a French notation. I generally use $\Bbb{R_0^+}$ for denoting that which I think most people use.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the star symbol $\big(~^\star~\big)$ indicates the lack of $0~\big($i.e., $\mathbb N^\star,~\mathbb Z^\star,~\mathbb Q^\star,~\mathbb R^\star,~\mathbb C^\star\big)$, and the plus sign $\big(+\big)$ means $\ge0$. Similarly for the minus sign $\big(-\big),~$ which implies $\le0$. Examples include $\mathbb Z_+~,~\mathbb Q_+~,~\mathbb R_+~,~\mathbb Z_-~,~\mathbb Q_-~,~\mathbb R_-~$ All of the above exclude infinity, since $\infty$ is not a number. We can define, however, sets such as the [extended real line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), $\overline{\mathbb R},~$ and the [extended complex plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), $\overline{\mathbb C}$.